# MarkupFactory - Markup not found, how to debug ResourceStreamLocator?

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to change the superclass of a WebPage to implement better menus.

What was

```
public class BasePage extends WebPage

public class TermsEditPage extends BasePage
```

is now

```
public abstract class IABasePage extends WebPage

public class TermsEditPage extends IABasePage
```

BasePage and IABasePage use

```
<wicket:child />
```

TermsEditPage uses

```
<wicket:extend>
```

IABasePage and TermsEditPage are in the same folder. BasePage is in a different folder.
I have tried IABasePage as abstract and not abstract but in both cases it crashes when the page is run.

```
09:53:54.548 [http-bio-8080-ex] ERROR o.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupFactory - Markup not found: Base markup of inherited markup not found. Component class: com.linguaclassica.instadmin.TermsEditPage. Enable debug messages for org.apache.wicket.core.util.resource.locator.ResourceStreamLocator to get a list of all filenames tried.
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Base markup of inherited markup not found. Component class: com.linguaclassica.instadmin.TermsEditPage. Enable debug messages for org.apache.wicket.core.util.resource.locator.ResourceStreamLocator to get a list of all filenames tried.
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.loader.InheritedMarkupMarkupLoader.loadMarkup(InheritedMarkupMarkupLoader.java:71) ~[wicket-core-6.20.0.jar:6.20.0]
```

How do I debug ResourceStreamLocator?
I do not have custom resources and am puzzled by the action.

Comment: Debug in this case means that you should put the logging output of org.apache.wicket.core.util.resource.locator.ResourceStreamLocator to DEBUG

Comment: I'd suggest to look for a typo in the names of the .html files. Usually this is the reason.

Comment: But how do I set ResourceStreamL‌​ocator to DEBUG?

Answer (score 1):

When I created the HTML files I did not notice that Eclipse created them in the *webapp* folder instead of the folder that I had selected. I never closed the files or had to open them. The program worked once the files were moved to the correct location.